# Why is clang-format: command not found

Tags: command-line, apt, 18.04, clang

The command was installed on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS using:

`sudo apt-get install clang-format`

with the following result:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  clang-format-6.0
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  clang-format clang-format-6.0
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
Need to get 638 kB of archives.
After this operation, 2,044 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe i386 clang-format-6.0 i386 1:6.0-1ubuntu2 [635 kB]
Get:2 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe i386 clang-format i386 1:6.0-41~exp4 [3,024 B]
Fetched 638 kB in 11s (59.1 kB/s)                                              
Selecting previously unselected package clang-format-6.0.
(Reading database ... 295327 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../clang-format-6.0_1%3a6.0-1ubuntu2_i386.deb ...
Unpacking clang-format-6.0 (1:6.0-1ubuntu2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package clang-format.
Preparing to unpack .../clang-format_1%3a6.0-41~exp4_i386.deb ...
Unpacking clang-format (1:6.0-41~exp4) ...
Setting up clang-format-6.0 (1:6.0-1ubuntu2) ...
Setting up clang-format (1:6.0-41~exp4) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2) ...
```

when running `man clang-format` as is expected:

`clang-format - manual page for clang-format 6.0`

the manpage is displayed.
but when running the command it says:

`clang-format: command not found`

**If anyone can clarify the reason for this (also why `clang-format-6.0` works instead of `clang-format`) would be great.**